# Why use int() in a Perl chmod?

Tags: perl, chmod

Why would you need to use the int() function when setting the perms on a file in Perl?

```
die "blab, blah"
    if (! chmod(int(0664), $tmp_file));
```

I can understand the use of oct() as in the following perldoc example:

```
$mode = "0644"; chmod(oct($mode), $tmp_file);
```

but the int() function?

**Edit**

Just for completeness, here's the recommendation from perldoc -f chmod ...

```
$mode = 0644;   chmod $mode, "foo";      # this is best
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It makes absolutely no sense. `0664` already results in an integer.

```
$ perl -MDevel::Peek -e'Dump(0664)'
SV = IV(0x7a6118) at 0x7a6128
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADTMP,IOK,READONLY,pIOK)
  IV = 436
```

`IOK` signals the scalar contains an integer value.

It's surely the result of someone starting with `oct("0644")` but not quite understanding what they were doing when they moved away from using a string.